# how to stop addContentView to hide the top of my expendablelistview?

Tags: android, view, addition

I need your help please, I have an expendablelistview in my expendablelistactivity
who is hide with my adding do with addContentView. How can I stop that?

I just want my expendablelistview follow my other view.

```
mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(context, groups, childrens);
this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

getWindow().addContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null),
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                45));

registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an ExpandableListActivity you have an ExpandableListView. Period. When you set the Adapter to it, You can't then add other View on top of that.(I'm almost sure this isn't good practice)

My advice is that you create an ExpadableListView on the side and put it into a Layout(with the other things you want) that is loaded into a clean plain Activity.

Helped?
JQCorreia

Comment: Actually, you can customize a `ListActivity` and `ExpandableListActivity`: see [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html), it says how.

Comment: Ok! bigstones is right! I didn't knew that... His link has the right method to do what you want